# ¿Cómo cambiar el titulo de una pestaña cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código en HTML:

`<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Phoenix StreamGaming</title>
</head>`

y este en JS:

```
document.title = '^ Phoenix StreamGaming ^';
```

Al hacer esto, inmediatamente me cambia el titulo. **Lo que quiero es que cada 3 segundos se actualice el titulo de la pestaña.**

*¡AGRADEZCO SUS RESPUESTAS!*

Comment: ¿Tienes definidos que titulos utilizar?

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado hasta ahora? Necesitamos un avance de tu código para partir de ahí y darte una solución.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías ejecutar la función **setInterval** la cual permite ejecutar una función cada cierto tiempo de una forma iterativa, esta función acepta 2 parámetros el primero es la función a ejecutar y el segundo es el tiempo en que se va a ejecutar la función en milisegundos:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Phoenix StreamGaming</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //Se crea la función a que se quiere ejecutar.
        function cambiarTitulo(){
            document.title = '^ Phoenix StreamGaming ^';
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    //Se manda a llamar el función setInterval.
    <body onLoad="setInterval('cambiarTitulo()',1000);">
</html>
```

Para mayor información [esta página](http://lineadecodigo.com/javascript/ejecutar-cada-x-segundos-en-javascript/)

Comment: Gracias amigo. Pero si lo queiro hacer de manera infinita como sería. Soy nuevo en JS y quisiera aprender con sus ayduas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con un call de la funcion setTimeOut:

```
 setTimeOut(function(){
 document.title = '^ Phoenix StreamGaming ^';
    setTimeOut(function(){
      document.title = '^ Phoenix StreamGaming ^';
   },1000) // segunda vez
 },1000) //primera vez
```

esta es una funcion ejemplo seria de ayuda

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], considera editar y agregar una explicación de tu respuesta

Comment: el formato lo estaba editando y sin querer aplique la funcion con la respuesta, gracias

Comment: Lo que necesito es que sea en bucle. (como la pestaña de omegle) en plan cada 3 segundos se actualice de forma infinita.

Answer (score 0):

agregale un loop while de la siguiente manera
`

```
       var sessionTimeoutWarning =   
@System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SessionWarning"].ToString();
 var sessionTimeout = @Session.Timeout;    
 var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
    setTimeout('SessionWarning()', sTimeout);

         function SessionWarning() {
           var message = "Your session will expire in another " + 
             (parseInt(sessionTimeout) - parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning)) + 
               " mins! Please Save the data before the session expires";
               alert(message);
                 }


           while(sTimeout < 0 )
                setTimeOut(function(){
                   document.title = '^ Phoenix StreamGaming ^';
                     setTimeOut(function(){
                     document.title = '^ Phoenix StreamGaming ^';
                       },1000) // segunda vez
                   },1000) //primera vez`
              return true;
                }
```

Al final puedes alertar al usuario que ha estado mas tiempo que la sesion fijate el tiempo de duración de la sesion  SessionWarning() y cuando eso acabe se termina el loop de tu mensaje es decir tienes que hacer que dure por cierto tiempo. saludos cap.

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregar una class con css tambien y dejar el setTimeOut

investiga sobre animation-iteration-count: infinite;

entonces creas una function donde la llamas luego y trabaja el setTimeout normalmente
aqui dejo el enlace https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Usando_animaciones_CSS